# Call Oracle Function from JDBC with User-Defined Types Collection

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

Good afternoon. I am trying to call a function where parameters are defined by a collection User-Defined Type. Problems arise (as I understand it) with a parameter that is defined as a collection(that is, when the type is defined as a table). I'm new to Oracle, but worked with other databases via jdbc

Oracle(12c):

```
type TParameterValue is record(
    Value varchar2(500),
    Name varchar2(500)
);


type TParameter is record(
    Code varchar2(100), 
    Value TParameterValue 
);

type TParameters is table of TParameter;


function ChangeEquipmentRequest(
    pParameters in TParameters
) return TChangeEquipmentResponse;
```

Java(ojdbc8 12.2):

```
connection = ...
OracleCallableStatement statement = (OracleCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall(String.join("",
                    "{?= call ",
                    config.getDbPrefix(),
                    ".CHANGEEQUIPMENTREQUEST(?)}"));

statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.STRUCT,config.getDbPrefix().concat(".TCHANGEEQUIPMENTRESPONSE"));

                Struct structValue = connection.createStruct(
                        config.getDbPrefix().concat(".TPARAMETERVALUE"),
                        new Object[]{"1","2"}
                );

                Struct structParam = connection.createStruct(
                        config.getDbPrefix().concat(".TPARAMETER"),
                        new Object[]{"code",structValue}
                );

                Object[] objects1 = new Object[]{structParam};
                Struct structParams = (Struct) connection.createStruct(
                        config.getDbPrefix().concat(".TPARAMETERS"),
                        objects1
                );

                statement.setObject(2, structParams, Types.STRUCT);
```

problems appear when I try to create a struct for a type *TPARAMETERS*

```
java.sql.SQLException:  Fail to construct descriptor: Invalid arguments
```

after that I googled that the collections in oracle are mapping as arrays

v2 with array:

```
            oracle.sql.ARRAY arrayParameters = (ARRAY) ((oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) connection).createOracleArray(
                    config.getDbPrefix().concat(".TPARAMETERS"),
                    new Object[]{structParam,structParam,structParam,structParam}
            );

statement.setObject(2, arrayParameters, Types.ARRAY);
```

i get:

```
PLS-00306: Invalid number or types of arguments when accessing 'CHANGEEQUIPMENTREQUEST'
```

as far as i understood this because of Types.ARRAY
so I still have to pass Types.STRUCT

on a note: I already use structs to describe types that are defined *is record* and it worked,
but if the type is defined as a collection(is table of XXX) I have to do something else

Thanks, any ideas?

Comment: Odd - I tried to reproduce this error but I couldn't. (I'm using Oracle 18c XE.) I was able to use your code to call the function and get a response from it.  I didn't have your `config` object so I replaced `config.getDbPrefix()` with a hard-coded string including the schema name and package name.  (I also made up a type for `TChangeEquipmentResponse` which you haven't included in your question.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What did you use for the mapping TParameters, array or struct ?

Comment: + if an array what should i use statement.setObject with Types.ARRAY or  statement.setARRAY?

Comment: I used `statement.setObject(2, arrayParameters, Types.ARRAY);` as per your "v2 with array" to set the parameter array.

Comment: For brevity, I deleted the field in the function with the boolean type, and as it turned out, the reason for the error was in it https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/apxtblsh.htm#JJDBC28981

Comment: "the field in the function with the boolean type"?  There's no boolean field in your question anywhere.  If the reason for your problem turns out to be in a detail that's omitted from the question, it's difficult for others to figure that out.  Please ensure that the code you post reproduces the problem you describe.